# How do I filter a script's arguments and save them to a new file?

Tags: bash, scripts, files, directory

I'm working on writing a bash script or command that will:

- Save to file `X` of from its arguments that are directories containing no more than 20 files.
- The name of file, represented by `X`, must be typed from keyboard.
- The file `X` should contain names of directories and their permissions.

I started by finding directories with no more than 20 files in this way:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{} '; ls '{}' | wc -l" \; | awk '$NF<=20'
```

But I'm having troubles saving arguments to a specific file.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - what did you try? what specific part(s) are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I started with finding directories with no more than 20 files in that way:


find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{} '; ls '{}' | wc -l" \; | 
 awk '$NF<=20'


But I'm having troubles with saving arguments to specific file

Comment: I don't think you're being asked to *find* directories - you are being asked to test whether arguments *are* directories (`for arg; do [ -d "$arg" ] ... ` or somesuch)

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a recursive descent?

Answer (score 0):

### Writing output to a file whose name was provided interactively by the user

You've said you're having trouble saving to a particular file whose name is provided by the user of the script, and you've emphasized wanting help with that specifically. But you didn't mention any trouble prompting the user to enter the filename. So I assume you have that working, and that you're doing something along the lines of `IFS= read -r outfile`, where `outfile` is the name of the variable that will hold the user-provided output filename.

If writing output to the file whose name is held in `outfile` is all you have left to do, then you already be very near to your goal. Replacing `outfile` with whatever variable name you chose...

- As with other [parameters in the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters), the variable you read into [can be expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) as `$outfile`, and you can and should [prevent](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) undesired [splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) by enclosing that in [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes), i.e., by writing `"$outfile"`.
- As with other filenames, you can use [output redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) to write to this file. So, just as you could use `>out.txt` to write to a file whose name is literally `out.txt`, you can write to the file whose name is held in your `outfile` variable by writing `>"$outfile"`.

That might be all you need. But there are some other modifications you might consider.

### You can use `find` and do *most* of what you need without `-exec`.

As [steeldriver says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152319/saving-script-arguments-to-new-file#comment1916037_1152319), from your stated goals it looks like you don't want your script to consider *all* the files in the current directory, as `find . -maxdepth 1 ...` does, but instead only consider the arguments passed to your script.

Still, it may well be reasonable to use `find` for this, and one benefit of doing so is that [if you do need](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152319/how-do-i-filter-a-scripts-arguments-and-save-them-to-a-new-file/1153684#comment1918593_1152319) to modify it to operate recursively later, that will be very easy. (On the other hand, it's often unwise to undertake extra effort to prepare for features you *might* need to add later, since it's hard to predict what features those will actually be.)

In the rest of this answer, I'll explore that possibility. I'll give what *might* be a full solution, but you may or may not decide it's acceptable for your needs. You'll likely want to modify it in some way. My goal isn't to provide a polished script, but instead to demonstrate techniques you can use. (You'll likely get other answers that demonstrate approaches like shell loops and checking each file with `[ -d filename ]` as [steeldriver suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152319/saving-script-arguments-to-new-file#comment1916037_1152319).)

If you want to use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html), you can pass on the arguments your script received to `find` as roots for its search in place of where you currently wrote `.`, and use `-maxdepth 0` so it doesn't actually descend into them. This *would* do the wrong thing if some of the filename arguments to your script start with `-`, since they could be interpreted specially by `find` (as options, predicates, or actions). But most commands treat arguments with leading `-` characters specially; usually it is sufficient to document this behavior for other users and to ensure you don't accidentally pass such paths to your script. (If you really want to consider an entry in the current directory named like `-foo`, you can pass its name as `./-foo` instead.)

For simplicity, I will first consider how to solve the easier problem of outputting lines for all arguments passed to the script that are names of directories, no matter how many entries they contain (i.e., ignoring the "no more than 20 files" requirement).

```bash
find "$@" -maxdepth 0 -type d -printf '%M %p\n' 2>/dev/null >"$outfile"
```

Here's how that works:

- [`"$@"` expands to a list of all the script's positional parameters.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) (The command-line arguments passed to your script become the values of its positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and so forth.) Each will be passed to `find` as a separate argument. This works even if some of the names contain spaces.
- `-maxdepth 0` tells `find` not to look any deeper than the paths you explicitly passed it. Therefore it will only consider the command-line arguments passed to your script.
- `-type d` finds only directories, just as you used it in your command.
- `-printf '%M %p\n'` prints an `ls`-style symbolic permissions string (`%M`), a space, the filename (`%p`), and ends the line (`\n`). See the documentation of the `-printf` action in [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html).
- I'm not sure, from your description, whether or not your script should consider it normal for the user to pass arguments that don't even identify any kind file at all, directory or otherwise. So, rather than make up requirements that might not apply to you, I've gone with the quick and dirty approach of suppressing all error messages from `find` with `2>/dev/null`. This redirects [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) ([file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 2) to `/dev/null` (a special "device" that [throws away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) its input). If you want to see error messages when arguments passed to your script don't name anything at all, just omit this part. (The script will still do its job, even though error messages are displayed. So they're effectively warnings rather than errors.) If you want some other behavior, you can work on this and/or give more information about your requirements. I call this a "quick and dirty" approach because it is possible for `find` to issue other error and warning messages, and they too would be suppressed.
- `>"$outfile"` writes to the output file whose name is held in the `outfile` variable, as described above.

One thing to consider is what happens if the user doesn't pass *any* arguments. Then `find` sees no roots to start with. When this happens, it behaves as if you passed `.`. (Not all `find` implementations treat the absence of roots as an implied `.`, but GNU find, the find implementation in Ubuntu, does.) You should handle this... if you don't want that behavior.

### Filtering directories containing more than 20 files

It's reasonable to use `-exec` to call another command that will count the files in each directory, and your approach to that is on the right track. But this should go *before* the `-printf` action (or whatever other action you use to cause `find` to output filenames), so that this action only happens for directories that pass the test.

If you choose to count the files by counting how many lines of output an [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ls.1.html) command produces, then that `ls` command should be invoked with the `-q` option. This is because filenames can contain weird characters you might not expect, *including [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters*. `-q` replaces such characters with `?`s, which for many purposes would be inadequate, but since you're not actually *looking* at the names, it's fine. (You may also want to use the `-1` option, because although [it is redundant](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting) when `ls` outputs to a [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) (as here), it clearly documents your intent that `ls` emit one line per file.) In general you should [avoid parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but since you don't care about the actual filenames and `-q` ensures you get one line per file, it is okay.

But I'll show a different technique instead. You can put this test after `-type d` but before `-printf`:

```bash
-exec bash -c 'a=("$1"/*); ((${#a[@]} <= 20))' _ {} \;
```

`bash -c ...` uses a `bash` shell. I've written `bash` instead of `sh` because there's a `bash` feature I want to use: [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). The shell runs `a=("$1"/*); ((${#a[@]} <= 20))`. In the first command, `a=("$1"/*)`:

- `"$1"` expands to the first [positional parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters), which corresponds to the filename `find` passes in place of `{}`. This is the name of the directory being processed.
- Writing `"$1"/*` [expands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) to the paths of the files contained in that directory, omitting those whose names start with `.`, like `ls` command did. (If you want to count those too, you can write `shopt -s dotglob;` before `a=...`.)
- Parenthesizing it on the right-hand side of a variable assignment [causes it to be stored in an array variable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Creating_Arrays-1).

The array is called `a` and [its size can later be obtained](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Intro) by writing `${#a[@]}`. The second command, `((${#a[@]} <= 20))`, takes advantage of that:

- `((` `))` [evaluates arithmetic expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) and returns true/success if they are nonzero, false/failure if they are zero.
- As mentioned above, `${#a[@]}` expands to the size of the array, which is the number of entries in the directory `find` passed in place of `{}`. This is what you need to compare to 20.
- `<= 20` compares it to 20.

You can try experimenting with other values than 20 to ensure it's working properly.

### Putting it all together

A full script could look something like this (but please remember, I don't know all your requirements, and this is intended much more as a demonstration than as a solution):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    printf '%s: warning: no arguments, behaving as "%s ."\n' "$0" "$0"
fi

printf 'Output filename> '
IFS= read -r outfile

find "$@" -maxdepth 0 -type d \
         -exec bash -c 'a=("$1"/*); ((${#a[@]} <= 20))' _ {} \; \
         -printf '%M %p\n' 2>/dev/null >"$outfile"
```

A few considerations:

- The user who runs the script must be careful what they enter as the output filename. **If that file exists, it will be overwritten.**
- I went ahead and demonstrated one possible way to deal with the case of no arguments: proceeding, but warning the user that it is as though they ran the script and passed `.`.
- Although the shell command run from `find`'s `-exec` action relies on `bash` for the array, the larger script that reads user input and calls `find` *doesn't* use any such features. You can run it with `bash` if you like and you can change the hashbang to `#!/bin/bash`. But I've gone head and written it as `#!/bin/sh`, as that should be sufficient.

I named my script file `lt20`. You can call it whatever you like, but you should make it executable by running `chmod +x lt20` (but with whatever name you did give it). Here's what it looks like to use the script, with text entered by the user shown in italics:

```
$ ./lt20 /usr/*
Output filename> out
$ cat out
drwxr-xr-x /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
drwxr-xr-x /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf
drwxr-xr-x /usr/games
drwxr-xr-x /usr/lib32
drwxr-xr-x /usr/libexec
drwxr-xr-x /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x /usr/src
```

My machine has twelve subdirectories of `/usr`, and they were all passed as arguments to the script, but only those with 20 or fewer entries (other that entries that started with `.`) were listed. All of them happened to have the same permissions, `drwxr-xr-x`, but the script only shows the same permission string for each entry when they actually have the same permissions.